# re.findall() creating a single list

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm very new to programming so forgive my ignorance.
I'm trying to use [0-9]+ to extract all the numbers that are scattered throughout the text. Using the below program I end up with a list for each line of text. How can I get all the numbers into a single list?

```py
import re
name = "regex.txt"
hand = open(name)
for line in hand :
    line = line.rstrip()

    num = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    print (num)
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck in trying to turn `num` string to individual numbers into a list?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to ingest the entire file as a single string:

```
full_text = hand.read()
num = re.findall('[0-9]+', full_text)
```